# Importing content into allocated ByteBuffer

Tags: java, buffer, bytebuffer

I have this file that I need to read using an allocated buffer:

```
ByteBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.allocate(n);
```

But I can't seem to understand how to move data into the buffer before I can print it to console.

I need to do this without using `CharBuffer`.

Comment: Why "without using `CharBuffer`"? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official way to read from a file into a `ByteBuffer` is a `FileChannel`:

- [`java.nio.channels.FileChannel`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html)

There are several ways to create `FileChannel` objects:

- [`java.io.FileInputStream.getChannel()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileInputStream.html#getChannel())
- [`java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#newByteChannel(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.OpenOption...))

The second method works on `Path` types, which can be obtained using [`java.io.File.getPath()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#getPath()), or from [`java.nio.file.FileSystem`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html).